# Python Docx, Python XML compatibility

Tags: python, python-docx

Needs assistance regarding Python Docx specifically with add_paragraph(). Trying to read data from .txt file and writing it to .docx file.

It seems like there is some special character at the end of text, I just need to ignore it somehow.

```
from docx import Document
    
document = Document()
    
with open("D:\\Python\\Jupyter Notebooks\\Python\\test.txt", 'r',) as textfile:
      for line in textfile.readlines():
        document.add_paragraph(line)
           
document.save('my_cake_file.docx')
```

getting following error:

ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters

[Here's the image of the text file where you can see the special character that I need to avoid while writing it to a word doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtHjy.png)

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the output of `print(repr(line))` for the line that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the ASCII character set, the range of printable characters starts with space having a numeric value of 32 (0x20) and ends at '~' with 126 (0x7E). Characters with value > 126 are non-printable characters such as FF which is the symbol in your example with a value of 255 or 0xFF. Control characters and other non-printable characters have ASCII range 0..31 some of which you may want to strip as well.

If you want to strip non-printable characters from end of text lines then you can reverse the characters in the string and find index of last printable ASCII character, and create a substring up to that index.

```python
from docx import Document
    
document = Document()
with open("test.txt", 'r') as textfile:
    for line in textfile.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip()
        idx = length = len(line)
        for c in line[::-1]:
            if ord(c) > 126:
                # character with ASCII value out of printable range
                idx -= 1
            else:
                # valid-character found
                break
        if idx < length:
            # strip non-printable characters from the end of the line
            line = line[0:idx]
        document.add_paragraph(line)
           
document.save('out.docx')
```

Depending on what characters should be preserved (e.g. whitespace, etc.), here's a simpler version using regexp to strip non-printable chars from the text. This version strips non-printable characters that appear anywhere in the text.

```python
from docx import Document
import re

with open("test.txt", 'r') as textfile:

    # printable includes digits + ascii_letters + punctuation + whitespace
    allpat = re.compile(f'[^{string.printable}]+')

    # end pattern matches other than digits + ascii_letters + punctuation
    # endpat = re.compile(r'[^\w!"#$%&\'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@^_`{|}\[\]~]+$')
    # or more succinct
    endpat = re.compile(f'[^\\w{string.punctuation}]+$')

    for line in textfile.readlines():
        # apply to end of line remove other than letters+digits+punctuation
        line = re.sub(endpat, '', line)
        # apply pattern to entire line removing all non-printable characters
        line = re.sub(allpat, '', line)
        document.add_paragraph(line)

document.save('out.docx')
```

Comment: I guess you can replace all that `new_line` stuff with `if line.endswith('\n'):`.

Comment: Also you can use `re.sub(r'\W+'. '', line)` to strip all non printable characters in just one pass.

Comment: Original poster wanted to preserve whitespace and trailing newline. Just wanted to strip out  non-printable chars from end of the line.

Comment: Not really. You can also use `str.splitlines()` and get an array with single lines.